# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete queryAbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)

Tags: spring, hibernate

I do have below in spring context.xml. Getting the error Executing an update/delete. Even with `q.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);` or without this. Might be I'm missing some configuration to update the tables

```
 @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Boolean updateXXXX(final EO workflowHistory) {
        Boolean updateFlag=false;
        String que = "update table  \n" + 
                     "set status =:statusname , \n" + 
                     "actor =:actor \n" + 
                     "where ID = ( \n" + 
                     "select MAX(id) from table \n" + 
                     "where \n" + 
                     "id =:processInstanceID)";

        try{
            final  Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(que);
            System.out.println("11 query...."+q.getLockMode());  
            q.setParameter("actor", workflowHistory.getActor());
            q.setParameter("statusname", workflowHistory.getStatus());
            q.setParameter("processInstanceID", workflowHistory.getProcessinstanceid());

            q.executeUpdate();

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("In updateWorkflowHistory....");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateFlag=true;
        return  updateFlag; 
    }
```

Comment: If you have Hibernate then why are you writing SQL queries and executing them. Use session.merge(updated_class_object); and this will update the existing row/s in the DB.

Comment: I need  "select MAX(id) from table \n" + 
                     "where \n" + 
                     "id =:processInstanceID" value so I dont want to do 2 transaction to databse

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below config to you spring context xml 
tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" 
will resolve the issue